# node.js, pg, postgresql and insert queries (app hangs)

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

I have the following simple node application for data insertion into postgres database:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var dbUrl = 'tcp://user:psw@localhost:5432/test-db';

pg.connect(dbUrl, function(err, client, done) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        client.query(
            'INSERT into post1 (title, body, created_at) VALUES($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id', 
            ['title', 'long... body...', new Date()], 
            function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('row inserted with id: ' + result.rows[0].id);
                }

            });
    }
});
```

After I run node app.js in terminal it inserts 1000 rows into database, then application hangs, and it do not terminates. What I am doing wrong? I have looked into pg module examples but didn’t spot that I’m doing any thing differently…

Comment: The application hangs due to your for loop executing as synchronous code. While it is iterating through the loop the node executable cannot respond to other requests. 

In addition the client.query calls are synchronous so as the for loop runs that query you will be slamming the data with all of these queries.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I missed call to the client.end(); Now application exits properly:

```
pg.connect(dbUrl, function(err, client, done) {
    var i = 0, count = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        client.query(
            'INSERT into post1 (title, body, created_at) VALUES($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id', 
            ['title', 'long... body...', new Date()], 
            function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('row inserted with id: ' + result.rows[0].id);
                }

                count++;
                console.log('count = ' + count);
                if (count == 1000) {
                    console.log('Client will end now!!!');
                    client.end();
                }
            });        
    }
});
```

Comment: Other way is to use client.on('drain', client.end.bind(client));

Comment: And what if the PG query fails for i = 207 ?
How do you handle this? Is the best way to use a single insert with many values?

That is, you let the for-loop build the query and you add proper escaping/checking of your data.