# Getting an error while inserting into postgres with a nodejs client

Tags: node.js, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to insert a record into Postgres DB with a Nodejs client.
The below URL in the code snippet contains JSON data.

Code Snippet:-

```
var pg = require("pg");
var req = require("request");
var url="http://localhost:6544/patients";

var connectionString = {
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'fhirbase',
  password: 'postgres',
  port: 5432,
};

var pool = new pg.Pool(connectionString);

pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {


    req.get(url, (error, response, body) => {

        if(error) {
            return console.dir(error);
        }

        else{

         data = JSON.parse(body);
         for(i=1;i<=data.length;i++){
             var v = data[i];
            const query=client.query(new pg.Query("INSERT INTO account VALUES ('5','5','patient',:data[i])"));

         }
        }})


})
```

Error:-events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
error: syntax error at or near ":"

Answer (score 0):

I think your way of querying is wrong, i maybe wrong here as i don't have knowledge about postgres but i think you have to use $1,$2 etc. Please refer to the below link you may get some idea of what i am trying to tell:

[node.js, pg, postgresql and insert queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319395/node-js-pg-postgresql-and-insert-queries-app-hangs)

Answer (score 0):

syntax error Obviously 
 `const query=client.query(new pg.Query("INSERT INTO account VALUES ('5','5','patient',:data[i])"));`
you can try

```
const query=client.query(new pg.Query("INSERT INTO account VALUES ('5','5','patient',data[i])"));
```